# SQL select first found value in 'in group'

Tags: mysql, select

Is is possible to select the first row matched in a list?

Table `bar`:
Column 'bar'
Values: value2, value3

```
SELECT * FROM `foo` WHERE `bar` IN ('value','value2','value3');
```

It select value2 and returns.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

The values I am expecting are:

```
Foo
Foobar
Foobarsome
Foobarsomething
```

I determine  this based on the length of the strings but I also need a default value if nothing is found. Lets say 'nothing' but nothing is bigger then foobar and could be a valid value.

Comment: what db server and version do you use? mysql? oracle? db2? ms sql?

Comment: ORDER BY FIELD() LIMIT 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a CASE statement in the ORDER BY clause to specify the order based on column values. Then use can use LIMIT to select just one row in the result.

```
SELECT * FROM foo 
WHERE bar IN ('value','value1','value2')
ORDER BY CASE bar WHEN 'value' THEN 1 WHEN 'value1' THEN 2 WHEN 'value2' THEN 3 ELSE 100 END
LIMIT 1;
```

I tested this example on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1523d/8/0).

**UPDATE:** The original poster edited the question and added that he wants to sort on string length and have a default value of 'nothing' returned if there are no results.

```
SELECT * FROM foo 
WHERE bar IN ('value','value1','value2')
ORDER by CASE bar WHEN 'value' THEN 1 WHEN 'value1' THEN 2 WHEN 'value2' THEN 3 ELSE 100 END
LIMIT 1;


SELECT bar FROM
(
  SELECT bar, 0 as SortOrder FROM foo 
  WHERE bar IN ('value','value1','value2')

  UNION
  SELECT 'nothing' as bar, 999 as SortOrder

) as x
ORDER BY SortOrder, LENGTH(bar)
LIMIT 1;
```

You can see the update query run in [SQL Fiddler](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1523d/14).

This solution works by using a UNION to combine the default value of 'nothing' to the result and also includes a "SortOrder" column. The UNION'ed queries are Order By the SortOrder column so that the default value is sorted to the bottom of the results, then the results are sorted by the length of bar. Finally there is LIMIT 1 clause so the default value 'nothing' appear in the final result if it is the only record otherwise the shortest string that matches in the 'in group' set is returned.

Comment: What does case actually do? ORDER BY CASE `fieldName` WHEN 'someValue' THEN 'what is this'?

Comment: Here is the MySQL documentation for the [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) statement. It is similar to a switch statement in other programming languages or a big If-ElseIf-ElseIf...Else statement. I have most often seen it used in the SELECT clause of a query, but can also be used in the ORDER BY.

Answer (score 2):

You can query:

```
 SELECT * FROM `foo` WHERE `bar` IN ('value','value2','value3') LIMIT 1;
```

But without additional ordering it's not deterministic, which first row will be your result.

Comment: This doesn't give back the first result of the in list. If actually gives back the last one? `bar` IN ('fooBarSome','fooBar','foo') if foobar and foo are found it returns foo but I am looking for the first found record. In thise case 'foobar'.

Comment: Okay, thats not what the IN predicate gives you. According to your comment, you want `If n-th value doesn't exist, give me (n+1)-th value`. But the edit you made to your question, says something about more than one result value.. now I'm confused :)

Comment: I have a list of possible values (this order of this list is made up by the user) the first value in the list is the one I want to select.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql should work with..

SELECT * 
FROM foo WHERE bar IN ('value','value2','value3')
LIMIT 0,1;

Could you please write your expected output? It will make it easier...